# How do I find the cell address of duplicates using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find, duplicates

I'm brand new to using VBA within excel. I'm not even 100% sure on how to insert a module correctly to begin with so this will be a big help.

I've set up a worksheet that randomizes a number between 1 and 100.

```
B3  =RANDBETWEEN(C6,F6)
```

I have 13 contestants. Each gets to guess a number. Goal is to be closest to the randomized number. (Guess a number between x & y. Closest wins "The Prize")

Contestants are listed in A9:B21. (i.e; "Contestant #1")

Their guesses are listed in C9:C21.

The difference between the randomized number and the guess is listed in D9:D21

```
D9:D21  =IF(C9>$B$3,C9-$B$3,IF($B$3>C9,$B$3-C9,0))
```

Cells F9:F21 let you know who won and doesn't count any guesses that are less than 1 and more than 100.

```
F9:F21  =IF(C9<1,,IF(C9>100,,IF(D9=MIN($D$9:$D$21),A9&" Wins",)))
```

Unfortunately, every time I try to reference in cell C6 or F6 instead of 1 or 100 I only get the result of 0.

In F8 I have a notification that pops up if there is a tie. Still not sure if this code is the best way to do this.

```
F8  =IF(COUNTIF(F9:F21,"*")>1,"Tie Breaker Needed","")
```

**Here's my question**. I know how to recognize duplicates and I can highlight them if I want to. I can't seem to find a way to have a single cell tell me exactly who has won even if there is a tie.

I.e; If Contestant #7 Wins --- Cell would say "Contestant #7 Wins"
     If Contestants #7 & #10 win --- Cell should say Contestant #7 & Contestant #10 Tie.

Is there a command or VBA module that could do this for me? I tried the VBA module below that I found but it only returns #NAME? No matter what I do.

Either this code works and I'm not inserting the module correctly or this module doesn't work for my situation and I need something new.

Help me Oh Great Excel Sages of the Online Realm.

[Image of My Excel Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3J89.png)
[image: Here's my Updated worksheet]

```
Option Explicit

Function LookupCSVResults(lookupValue As Integer, lookupRange As Range, resultsRange As Range) As String

    Dim s As String 'Results placeholder
    Dim sTmp As String  'Cell value placeholder
    Dim r As Long   'Row
    Dim c As Long   'Column
    Const strDelimiter = "|||"  'Makes InStr more robust

    s = strDelimiter
    For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
            If lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value = lookupValue Then
                'I know it's weird to use offset but it works even if the two ranges
                'are of different sizes and it's the same way that SUMIF works
                sTmp = resultsRange.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
                If InStr(1, s, strDelimiter & sTmp & strDelimiter) = 0 Then
                    s = s & sTmp & strDelimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Now make it look like CSV
    s = Replace(s, strDelimiter, ",")
    If Left(s, 1) = "," Then s = Mid(s, 2)
    If Right(s, 1) = "," Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    LookupCSVResults = s 'Return the function

End Function
```

Comment: Do you need to do it in VBA?  It can be done by formula....

Comment: It doesn't have to be done in VBA. I just hadn't found a way to do it in a single cell without using VBA until now.

Comment: My contestants are in A1:C11 with B & C being their predictions.  The actual results are in E2 & F2

Comment: H2 to H11, you have the array formula =IFERROR(SMALL(IF((($B$2:$B$11=$E$2)*($C$2:$C$11=$F$2)),ROW($B$2:$B$11)-1),ROWS($B$2:$B3)),"")

Comment: I2 to I11, you have the normal formula =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,H2,1),"")

Comment: The use concatenate to combine the results, so i had 2 winners, so was

Comment: =CONCATENATE(I2,IF(I3<>"", " and " & I3,"")) and so on....

Comment: gives me the result "Person 3 and Person 8"

Comment: @Nathan_Sav 
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((($C$9:$C$21=$B$3)),ROW($C$9:$C$21)-1),ROWS($C$9:$C9)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$9:$A$21,I9,1),"")

Comment: =CONCATENATE(J9,IF(J10<>"", " and " & J10,""))

Comment: Still not working for me using it for my sheet. Suggestions

Comment: Without seeing what you've done or your sheet, no suggestions :)

Comment: If I edit my post, can I attach my current worksheet?

Comment: I've shown an image of what my worksheet looks like right now

Comment: You havent applied my formula correctly, you are only checking b3, and you need to fill it down 19:i21.  Look at my original comments, ((($B$2:$B$11=$E$2)*($C$2:$C$11=$F$2) and I2 to I11 etc...  They are array formula also, so ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav
It was copied down but I hadn't made it an array. Now I have but I get no result. I'm not sure what else I should be checking beside B3 because that's the only relevant number. unless I'm misunderstanding what the first function truly does.

Comment: Sorry, i had it in my head for some reason, the contestants picked 2 numbers, also you are looking for "the random number is 5"

Comment: I've simply changed the format of that cell so that what ever number is returned has "The Random Number Is " in front of it.

Comment: I've just copied your sheet, and used =IFERROR(SMALL(IF($C$9:$C$20=$B$3,ROW($C$9:$C$20)-8),ROWS($I$9:$I9)),"") and it works fine.   I cant attach an image for some reason to show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following *UDF()*:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ListWinners(people As Range, deltas As Range) As String
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Dim i As Long, delta As Long, msg As String
   Dim WinningValue As Long
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   ListWinners = ""
   msg = " wins"
   WinningValue = wf.Min(deltas)
   For i = 1 To deltas.Rows.Count
      If deltas(i) = WinningValue Then
         If ListWinners = "" Then
            ListWinners = people(i)
         Else
            ListWinners = ListWinners & " & " & people(i)
            msg = " tie"
         End If
      End If
   Next i
   ListWinners = ListWinners & msg
End Function
```

In your posted example, use it like:

```
=ListWinners(A9:A21,C9:C21)
```

to display the winner list in a **single cell.**

**EDIT#1:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, **you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=ListWinners(A1:A100,B1:B100)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks. This helps except for 1 thing. When I hit F9 to refresh my page and get a new Random number, I do not get The correct winner. I've copied in this Code into VBA and then used the ListWinners command but It doesn't always give me the correct answer. Suggestions?

Comment: I figured out my problem. I had "=ListWinners(A9:B21,D9:D21)" and it needed to be A9:A21. Now it works. Thank you so much. Any chance we can add a clause in this code? Right now if a contestant doesn't guess and leaves their answer at "0" and the random number chooses "1", they win even though they aren't playing. Can it check column "C" first to make sure a number between the specified Max and Min of the Random number is entered?

Comment: Just make the default value something like **9999** rather than **0**

Comment: I just shut my page down and when I re-opened this workbook, I'm getting a Name Error for ListWinners. Thoughts on what I did wrong? Did I somehow screw up inserting the Module into VBA?

Comment: I also noticed that row 5 of your code has "delta " spelled in the singular and everywhere else in the code it is "deltas". Is that on purpose?

Comment: The `delta` variable is Declared, but not used...........................se my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Thank you. You have been sooooo helpful. Don't know what changed but I re-saved my worksheet and unable to run VBA the re-saved again to run VBA again. Then I deleted my former ListWinners Module and copy-pasted your current ListWinners Module code using your instructions. Works again. Thanks.